# Change An Image On A Website Using Tampermonkey

Tags: image, replace, tampermonkey

I want to change an image on a website, so that every time I visit, it shows the image that I want it to show and not the one that it normally shows.

Does anyone have the Tampermonkey code to do this?

Comment: What is the URL of the image you would like to replace?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `src` attribute. For example, say your image has the id "blah":

```
document.getElementById("blah").src = "http://......"
```

If you're not just searching by id, you could use something like `document.querySelector(.....)` instead.

Then put this inside a TamperMonkey script and make sure your code is firing on the correct websites (the `@match` part of the UserScript section in your script).

Answer (score 1):

The following example is a tampermonkey script that runs on all websites. The script searches for an image of a cat and replaces it with an image of a dog. This script uses jQuery to select the image and modify its value.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Image Replacer
// @version      1.1
// @description  Image Replacer
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// @match        https://www.pinterest.com/pin/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

/*globals $*/

var old_url = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/21/64/6a/21646ad49e3860218f44b456153c7594.jpg"
var new_url = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/59/9b/bb/599bbb49d7a3bb5546ff4017e9eb76ce.jpg"
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Hi There!");
    $("img[src='"+old_url+"']").attr("src", new_url);
    alert("Replaced pictures successfully");
});
```

You can run this script on this [Pinterest Website](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/381187555961478162/).